# Read io stats for a particular process id

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How do I read the I/O stats for a particular process in Android linux kernel. `/proc/stat` gives the general cpu io wait time spent, but not for a particular process. I tried using `/proc/<pid>/stat` which has all the information about a process. But it didn't work out.

Comment: How did it not work out, what were your expectations? `iotop` is usually a good first bet.

Comment: Anders The file /proc/pid/io is different in Android linux kernel. It is not the same as Pc's linux kernel. The number of fields in Android linux kernel /proc/pid/io file is lesser than pc's kernel file.

Comment: Is `/proc/$PID/io` sufficient for  your needs?

Comment: EarlGray there is a correction. Its /proc/pid/stat and not /proc/pid/io. I made a mistake in my previous comment